# Laravel sending mail over gmail

Tags: laravel, email, gmail, send

I can't seem to get this to work:

**ENV**:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my_acc@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**In controller:**

```
Mail::send('mail.template', ['post' => $post, 'user' => $user], function($message) {
            $message->to('my_acc@gmail.com', 'X Y')->subject('Comment');
        });
```

And I get error:

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I have tried adding this to `StreamBuffer.php`

```
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
```

And then I get this error:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

And even if I didn't get that error, I would like a solution, not a quick fix...

Comment: Do you have two factor authentication enabled on your gmail account?

Comment: No, but I tried with it also. Should it be enabled or not? Logic suggests not :)

Comment: That's personal preference, if you do have it enabled you need to generate an app password to get access to it through your app.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind...but I don't have it now, and the error is there

Comment: For the record, I encountered the same issue and the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378067/symfony-swiftmailer-via-smtp-gmail-on-localhost-openssl-error) corrected this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use your `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` and should work fine.

Comment: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Try to change the port also to 465.

Comment: Check if your openssl extension is enabled in your php.ini. If not, enable and try again.

Comment: Laravel doesn't have php.ini file?

Comment: No, your PHP installation will have one. Try to run `php -i | grep php.ini` in terminal to know where your php.ini file is located.

Comment: PHP is drawn from my WAMP installation, and I have found extension=php_openssl.dll uncommented. Is that it?

Comment: Weird, try to check if your apache mod_ssl module is active and try again.

Comment: Where can I check that?

Comment: In WAMP, I think is by clicking in the icon on the bottom right, then Apache > Modules > mod_ssl (or something like that).